# Expect + Buffer not matching

Tags: expect

While executing below code it is not executing expect first clause where I am sending the `df -h` command. While second clause which is password reset clause is working fine.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set ip [lindex $argv 0]
spawn ssh  anshm@$ip
set timeout 10
match_max 40000
exp_internal -f debug_info.log 0
expect "*word"
send "5t6y%T^Y\n"
expect {
    "localhost*$" {
        send "df -h\r"
        expect eof
    }
    "(curr*assword:" {
        send "5t6y%T^Y\r"
        expect "*word"
        send "7u8i&U*I\r"
        expect "*word"
        send "7u8i&U*I\r"
        expect eof
    }
}
```

Debug information is below:

```
1034h[anshm@localhost ~]$ " (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "localhost*$"? no
"(curr*assword:"? no
expect: timed out
```

If you see last line then this "localhost*$" is appears in buffer still it is showing match NO and then timing out.

Comment: Remove the `exp_internal` line and `expect -d /your/script.ex` and post the output.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be suffering from a bug/feature of `expect` glob pattern matching.

Why does input `"...nshm@localhost ~]$ "` not match glob pattern `"localhost*$"`?
When the `$` character is the *last character* in a glob pattern means *end-of-input-string*, so in principle the `*` should match absolutely anything following `localhost`. However, for some reason `*$` at the end of the pattern does not work in this way, though, for example, `x$` does indeed only match `x` at the end of input.

However, you really wanted to match a literal `$` character. To do this use `\\$`. So your glob pattern should be

```
"localhost*\\$"
```

Comment: `$` has no special meaning for **glob** patterns. You are thinking of regular expressions.

Comment: Huh, you're right. I'll provide more detail in a followup answer.

Answer (score 0):

@meuh is right: even in a glob pattern, a *trailing* `$` is **not** a literal character.

```
$ expect -d <<'END_EXPECT'
spawn sh -c {echo first; echo second localhost other info '$dollar sign '; echo third}
expect "second"
expect {
    {localhost*$}  {puts "found 1: >>$expect_out(0,string)<<"}
    {localhost*$*} {puts "found 2: >>$expect_out(0,string)<<"}
}
END_EXPECT
```

```
expect version 5.45
argv[0] = expect  argv[1] = -d
set argc 0
set argv0 "expect"
set argv ""
executing commands from command file
spawn sh -c echo first; echo second localhost other info '$dollar sign '; echo third
parent: waiting for sync byte
parent: telling child to go ahead
parent: now unsynchronized from child
spawn: returns {2595}

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "second"? no
first
second localhost other info $dollar sign
third

expect: does "first\r\nsecond localhost other info $dollar sign \r\nthird\r\n" (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "second"? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "second"
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp4"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "first\r\nsecond"

expect: does " localhost other info $dollar sign \r\nthird\r\n" (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "localhost*$"? no
"localhost*$*"? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "localhost other info $dollar sign \r\nthird\r\n"
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp4"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) " localhost other info $dollar sign \r\nthird\r\n"
found 2: >>localhost other info $dollar sign
third
<<
```

I'd recommend using a regex pattern instead of adding `*` to the end of your glob pattern:

```
expect -re {localhost.*\$} {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thankyou Guys, for your valuable answers. But i have done some debuging and found that expect not considering it as character so I used localhost only and problem get solved.
But If any one has any idea about assigning expect o/p in a variable and use it for condition statement like:
If { $variable < Something } { Put "ABCD" }
else { Put "DEFG" }

Any Valuable suggestion are welcome in advance.